# they are being removed or they are removed?

Tags: passive-voice

which one is correct

**they are being removed from the black list?**

or

**they are removed from the black list?**

i want to use a passive sentence to express the removal of something from the black list.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better asked on ELL. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the context, but I would guess you need the first. That’s what you would use to describe an action in progress. Later you might say ‘They have been removed from the black list.’